# Django Rest Framework not hashing my password

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I am trying to register a user in my Blog-API that I build using Django Rest Framework. Here is my code (serializers.py):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.serializers import (ModelSerializer,
                                        HyperlinkedIdentityField,
                                        SerializerMethodField)

User = get_user_model()  


class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
       ]
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True}
    }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        email = validated_data['email']
        password = validated_data['password']
        user_obj = User(username=username,
                        email=email)
        user_obj.set_password(password)
        user_obj.save()
        return validated_data
```

In the Django admin the user will appear as expected. However, the password is said to be of invalid format.
Can somebody point me toward a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. Stupid Indentation problem for the create() method.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.serializers import (ModelSerializer,
                                        HyperlinkedIdentityField,
                                        SerializerMethodField)

User = get_user_model()  


class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = [
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
       ]
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {'write_only': True}
    }

def create(self, validated_data):
   username = validated_data['username']
   email = validated_data['email']
   password = validated_data['password']
   user_obj = User(username=username,
                    email=email)
   user_obj.set_password(password)
   user_obj.save()
   return validated_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Your create method should return `user_obj` and not `validate_data`. Your string `password` seems to be overwrite the objects password-field after your call to set_password, perhaps somewhere else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved like this

```
class  CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'password',
    ]
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password' : {'write_only' : True},
    }

def create(self,validate_data):

    user = User.objects.create_user(username = validate_data['username'] , password = validate_data['password'])

    return user
```

Views.py (just calling lines)

```
                temp_data = {
                    'username' : username,
                    'password' : password,
                }
                serializer = CreateUserSerializer(data = temp_data)
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)                    
                user = serializer.save()
```

create_user will take care of hashing.